# What are methods used to identify the system call and pass function tasks to the operating system?

Tags: windows, function, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

Is this based on context switching that schedules processes on the cpu? Im a bit lost with understand how this works

Comment: It not clear what you're trying to ask. Maybe try using an example.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding your question, you are asking the implementation mechanism of `system call`. So you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Typical_implementations

Answer (score 0):

system call is not context switch based. context switch is exchange of process running on cpu. which call is going to be used is decided on the system call number which is used as index in system call table. only process context is changed from user to kernel. I always suggest for reading understanding linux kernel an excellent book